# Conditionally removing custom object ArrayList elements during iteration

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, collections, logical-operators

I am working on java requirement where I need to remove some of ArrayList elements based on few conditions.

Here is my code:

```
package com.demo.test;

public class ProductBean {


    public ProductBean(int code,String name,String type,String status){
        this.productCode=code;
        this.productType=type;
        this.productName=name;
        this.productStatus=status;

    }

    public int getProductCode() {
        return productCode;
    }
    public void setProductCode(int productCode) {
        this.productCode = productCode;
    }
    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }
    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }
    public String getProductType() {
        return productType;
    }
    public void setProductType(String productType) {
        this.productType = productType;
    }
    public String getProductStatus() {
        return productStatus;
    }
    public void setProductStatus(String productStatus) {
        this.productStatus = productStatus;
    }
    private String productName;
    private String productType;
    private String productStatus;
    private int productCode;


    public String toString(){

        return"prduct details are : "+this.productCode+" "+this.productName+" "+this.productType+" "+this.productStatus;
    }

}
```

Test Class:

```
package com.demo.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ProductTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ProductBean p1=new ProductBean(1, "product1", "toy", "S1");
        ProductBean p2=new ProductBean(2, "product2", "toy", "S1");
        ProductBean p3=new ProductBean(3, "product3", "toy", "S1");
        ProductBean p4=new ProductBean(4, "product4", "toy", "S1");
        ProductBean p5=new ProductBean(5, "product5", "toy", "S2");
        ProductBean p6=new ProductBean(6, "product6", "toy", "S2");
        ProductBean p7=new ProductBean(7, "product7", "toy", "S2");
        ProductBean p8=new ProductBean(8, "product8", "toy", "S2");
        ProductBean p9=new ProductBean(9, "product9", "toy", "S2");
        ArrayList<ProductBean> productList=new ArrayList<ProductBean>();
        productList.add(p1);
        productList.add(p2);
        productList.add(p3);
        productList.add(p4);
        productList.add(p5);
        productList.add(p6);
        productList.add(p7);
        productList.add(p8);
        productList.add(p9);

        int requiredProductCode=2;
        String requiredProductStatus="S1";

        Iterator<ProductBean> itr=productList.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){

            ProductBean pbean=itr.next();
            if(pbean.getProductCode()<=requiredProductCode){
                itr.remove();
            }
            if(!pbean.getProductStatus().equals(requiredProductStatus)){
                itr.remove();
            }

        }


        for(ProductBean pbean1:productList){
            System.out.println(pbean1);
        }

    }

}
```

I have to remove product objects from list based on below conditions.

1. when ProcuductCode of listObject is less than or equal to
   requiredProductCode the object should be removed.
2. when productStatus of listobject is not equal to
   requiredProductstatus the object should be removed.

Desired/Actual output

```
prduct details are : 3 product3 toy S1
prduct details are : 4 product4 toy S1
```

I have tried to achieve this using AND(&&) OR(||) operators but not getting the desired output. I ended up using two if conditions inside while loop.Kindly improve suggest improvements for this code piece ..using some logical operators to avoid two if conditions inside the code.

Comment: Try changing your second `if` to an `else if` so you don't remove two things if both statements are true.

Comment: Can I have two compare statements in single if condition using any other logical operator to get desired output ?

Comment: Your `if` condition is falling...

Comment: You could merge them using `||` if you want to. `if ((bean.getProductCode()<=requiredProductCode) || (!pbean.getProductStatus().equals(requiredProductStatus)))`. This also works instead of changing it to `else if`.

Comment: `if((pbean.getProductCode()<=requiredProductCode) ||(!pbean.getProductStatus().equals(requiredProductStatus)){
    itr.remove();
}` what is wrong in this..

Comment: @zar  if I use || second statement is not validating...I mean even when object procutCode is greater than 2..it should check product status if it is not equal to "S1" the object must be removed

Comment: I am confused about your conditions. I thought you said  if the code is less than or equal to the required code OR the product status doesn't equal the required status it is removed. Is this incorrect? What are the conditions?

Comment: @zar sorry for confusing...I have modified code as u suggested and its working fine..thanks for help :)

Comment: No problem, if you don't mind, I'll add it as an answer you can accept.

Comment: @Zar  sure ..u can mark as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now if the conditions in both `if` statements are true you'll remove two things instead of one. You can make the second an `else if` or merge the two into a single `if` like this:

`if ((bean.getProductCode()<=requiredProductCode) || (!pbean.getProductStatus().equals(requiredProductStatus)))`